# What is the right way to plumb bathroom drainage across small joists?

Tags: plumbing, drain, structural, old-house

Finished the demo part of the bathroom remodel to find pretty significant damage to the floor joists caused by the original builder's "design" (see photos/video). Setting aside how I'm going to fix or at least mitigate the damage - what would have been the correct way to plumb in the toilet and sink drains without weakening the structure?

Given the small floor joists, I can't imagine the right way to try to drain across them this way. So what would a pro builder have done to install this bathroom correctly?

[image]

[More photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuhV6.jpg)

More context:
This is the 2nd floor of a 2-story, 1920s house. This bathroom and its stack are directly above the 1st-story bathroom. The stack is perfectly vertical from the basement to the attic, where it has a slight offset to exit the roof. The existing stack is cast iron and all existing drains are steel/iron.

The toilet drain pipe in the wall drains both upper and lower commodes before Y-ing into the main stack 5' above the basement floor.

Comment: It's difficult to apply modern techniques to an old solid wood floor system with potentially low ceilings. Those are rare beasts anymore. The short answer is that the plumbing should've been _below_ the joists, not through them. Is that an option given your basement ceiling height?

Comment: @isherwood, it's not over a basement in this case, since we're looking at the second floor.  I'm not sure how you'd get plumbing under the joists in that case.

Comment: I have some ceiling height to spare. Without doing a bit more demo, it may still be a challenge to tie into structure that should be carrying load.

@SteveSether I agree it has managed well enough for several decades. Basically every interior wall is load-bearing; that's an issue for other reasons but probably helped in this case.